# Ubuntu 14.04 on VirtualBox needs Guest Additions but resolution is too small to open a terminal.

Tags: virtualbox, ubuntu-14.04

I have installed Ubuntu 14.04 on a VirtualBox running on a Windows host. The resolution is stuck at 640x480. I have found many solutions suggesting that Guest Additions is needed to resolve this issue, but at the current resolution, there appears to be no way to open a terminal to run apt.

Suggestions?

Comment: `CTRL + ALT + F1` inside your guest

Comment: ahh, that helps. It opens the terminal in full screen though. How do I exit back to the desktop?

Comment: `ALT + F7` or `CTRL + ALT + F7`

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you are now at windows.

1. open VirtualBox
2. start your ubuntu
3. On popup window which running ubuntu, find the menu"Machine, View,
   Devices, Help"
4. **Select: Device-> Insert Guest Additions CD image...**

After installation, Reboot your ubuntu. And Done!

P.S. Those answers that using Terminal input commands such as 
    "sudo apt-get install virtualbox-guest-dkms virtualbox-guest-utils virtualbox-guest-x11"
Requires install "Insert Guest Additions" by yourself first.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.linuxbsdos.com/2014/10/31/solutions-for-low-screen-resolution-in-ubuntu-14-0414-10-and-virtualbox/

I followed this advice but found 1024x768 wqas available just by enabling xdiagnose as suggested, without the need to download the drivers. YMMV.

Answer (score 0):

I tried several things but this worked for me.

I Changed display size like this (Preference -> display)

[image]

and then run those 3 commands in terminal:

```
    sudo apt-get remove libcheese-gtk23, 
    sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-core 
    sudo apt-get install -f virtualbox-guest-x11
```

and then restart